# Global varaibles are bad, but are used by default in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

Every one saids, don't use Global variables, they are bad, and that's ok. But in Python if you don't do anything all variables are gobal by default.
There's any way to change this?. Thank you in advances. Regards. Sorry abour my english..

```
def function():
    dic['one']=35

dic={}
function()
print(dic)
```

Comment: What do you mean, global by default? It depends where you define them. Variables are only global when defined outside any function or class.

Comment: Not always true. If you declare INSIDE a function, it's local. AND there are keywords `nonlocal` and `global` if you must modify non-local variables.

Comment: You declared your variables outside of any function, so they are global. What should they be local _to_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **global variable** is a named variable whose value can be reassigned from any scope.  In order to reach into a higher scope and reassign a variable that was defined there, you need to explicitly use the `global` or `nonlocal` keyword.  For example:

```
def function():
    global foo
    foo = 5

foo = 3
function()
print(foo)  # prints 5
```

Variables are **not** global by default:

```
def function():
    foo = 5

foo = 3
function()
print(foo)  # prints 3
```

In your example, the variable `dic` is not itself being modified, but rather the value that it references (this is possible because dictionaries are a **mutable** type of value; you can modify the contents of a dictionary via the `[]` operator).  If we try to modify the variable `dic` inside the function, this change is not reflected in the outer scope:

```
def function():
    dic = {'one': 35}

dic={}
function()
print(dic) # prints {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I knew de difference, I tray to find an answer about why if you don say anything the variable are Global, I thought  there was some thing I din't coud saw. I was ill, sorry to thank you late.